# Derivative of matrix determinant wrt to matrix element

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus

I want to take the derivative of the function:

$$
f(A) = 2  + \text{log}(|\text{det}(A)|)
$$

with respect to the matrix element $A_{ij}$, where A is orthogonal, so far:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}f(A) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}} \text{log}(|\text{det}(A)|)\\
& = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}|\text{det(A)}|}{|\text{det(A)}|} \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}|\text{det(A)}|
\end{align*}

I'm not really sure how to proceed, my first instinct was to note that $det(A) = I$ for an orthogonal matrix, but i guess here I am trying to find how the determinant changes wrt a matrix element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Jacobi's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}f(A) &=& \frac{\partial }{\partial A_{ij}} \left( 2 + \log |\det(A)|\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{|\det(A)|}\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}\det (A) = C_{ij}(A)
\end{eqnarray}

where $C(A)$ is the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of A